# Distance to subspace spanned by two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

i am finding difficulty in the following problem:

let W=span{$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$(0,0,1,1),$\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$(1,-1,0,0)}

be a subspace of the euclidean space $\Bbb R^4$.

then,what is the square of distance from the point (1,1,1,1) to the subspace W ??

thanks a lot...

Comment: Do you know how the distance from a point to a subspace is defined?

Comment: @ Michael Albanese:no...it is not clear to me

Comment: Where did you get this problem from? Was the distance not defined in that book/class?

Comment: @ Michael Albanese:this is problem from an entrance exam.i know it is a very basic problem but i am not able to solve it...could you mention some textbook where i can get it

Comment: @vikashtripathi: Are you supposed to submit a solution to exactly this problem?